How to get the first order for a given subscription in Laravel?
I have a custom plan subscription project in Laravel, I have this models:
Order:
- id
- amount
- plan_id

Plan:
- id
- name
- price

Subscription:
- id
- plan_id
- starts_at
- ends_at
- subscriber_type
- subscriber_id

Client:
- id
- name

Here subscriber_type is App\Models\Client and subscriber_id is the client id
Plan.php
class Plan extends Model implements Sortable
{  

    public function subscriptions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }

    public function orders(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
  ....
}

Subscription.php
class Subscription extends Model{

public function plan(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Plan::class);
    }

}

Client.php
class Client extends Model{

    public function suscriptions(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Subscription::class, 'subscriber', 'subscriber_type', 'subscriber_id');
    }
}

Order.php
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function client(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }           
}

When a subscription is created, an order is created too with the plan_id.
I can get all the subscriptions by a given client
$client->suscriptions()->get();
But the problem is that also along with the subscription, I need to get the first order created for that user for that plan/subscription how can I do that?
EDIT:
I was able to do it partially:
$client->subscriptions()->with(['plan.orders' => function ($query) use ($client) {
            $query->where('client_id', $client->id)
                ->orderBy('created_at');
}]);

the problem with this approach, is that I get all the orders that belongs to the plan and user, I just want the first one
$client->subscriptions()->with(['plan.orders' => function ($query) use ($client) {
            $query->where('client_id', $client->id)
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->first();
}]);

The problem here that the only in the first subscription result it get the first order, but in the second subscription I get the orders empty: "orders": []
What can I do?

What does the Order model look like? How is the relationship defined between it and User / Subscription?

Try like this and little might be help your problem.
Client make relation with Subscription and Subscription make with Plan and then Plan make with Order. So when you create subscription, you have to store subscription, plan and order at the same time or if you don't want to create order at the same time, you can recall with plan_id and client will make Order under that plan_id later but make sure you have already created the plan when client make subscribe on something. so you can call the first order like that
$client = Client::with(['subscriptions' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['plan.order' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first();
    }]);
}])->find($clientId);

or you can define single subscription like that
 $client->subscription(function ($query) {
    $query->with(['plan.order' => function ($query) {
       $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first();
    }]);
 });


with the first code i get this: Nested arrays may not be passed to whereIn method.
and with the second it return an empty array
